# Change Rave Report datatext1 color

Tags: delphi, rave-reports

I want to set a Rave Report datatext color with Delphi

```
if Edit1.text='0' then datatext1.color= green;//for example
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have a link to Nevrona, indicating how to set text font, color, etc., "on the fly" in reports: [Tip #36 - In-Text Formatting In Rave](http://www.nevrona.com/rave/tips/rvtip36.html).

Comment: My bad, I filled in the edit reason wrongly. [Please read the FAQ concerning signatures and taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: @Alexander - it seems that you're editing almost all my questions/answers. I need to thank you for such a job, so 'up' for the last comment

Comment: If they appear in my search results I will surely bump into them. Thanks, no problem :)